# how to instantiate a CD entity without being fetched

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a program that fetches from `Core Data` and then within the program if something is fetches it displays the results in my `UITableView`.

Now my problem is that sometimes I need the user to add another `UITableCell` to my `UITableView` but my `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` counts the elements in my array which holds my `ExerciseData` entities.

I've tried to create an `ExerciseData` entity as if it was an object but this doesnt work and crashes the program.
by doing

```
 if ([[_ed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] weight]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",_ed);
             cell.weightInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_ed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] weight]];
        }
```

it throws the error `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'ExerciseData'` that made me understand that I cant initiate a CD entity like that.

then I've tried to add to the `NSArray _ed` a `NSString` and then check for the class and if the `class type` was a class of `NSString` it shouldnt try to set  `cell.weightInput.text`

My question are 2: 
1) Is there a way to initiate an entity so that I can insert it in the array and then check if is empty so that then i can validate it on a later `if statement`?

if that is not possible
2) How could i populate the `NSArray` with something that can then be validated & escalated to multimple items but also work when there is a `ExerciseData`?

My goal is that the person uses `- addSet` to create a new `UITableCell` for as many times the button is pressed then i need to validate whatever is inside so that if is a `ExerciseData entity` and the property weight is set to populate `cell.weightInput.text` or otherwise dont populate it

```
- (void) addNewSet {
     ExerciseData * newEd = [[ExerciseData alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray* ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_ed];
    [ar addObject:newEd];
    _ed = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:ar];
    [_mytable reloadData];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    workoutCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[workoutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.weightInput.text = @"";
    if ( indexPath.row < [_ed count] ) {
        if (![[[_ed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] class] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",_ed);
             cell.weightInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_ed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] weight]];
        }
    }
//...
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ( [_ed count] == 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [_ed count];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new CoreData entity you need to:

```
ExerciseData *data = (ExerciseData*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExerciseData" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
```

Make sure to save your context after!